# Casting TextMessage to a MapMessage - Java

Tags: java

I have a `Message` that is passed to a method like this:

```
public void methodX(Message message) {
}
```

In it I have a logger that the scan is giving me some warnings about, so I thought instead of printing it right out of the bat and cast it to a `TextMessage`, now the scan warning disappeared, but I'm concerned about the outcome of the message printed, this is how it used to be:

```
public void methodX(Message message) {
    logger.debug("Received message: " + message.toString());
    try {
        if(message instanceof MapMessage) {
            MapMessage mm = (MapMessage) message;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I modified it:

```
public void methodX(Message message) {
    try {
        if(message instanceof MapMessage) {
            logger.debug("Received message: " + (TextMessage) message);

            MapMessage mm = (MapMessage) message;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If the message that is being passed is a `MapMessage`, will casting it like above to `TextMessage` cause a different print result from the original implementation?

Comment: What scan? What problem are you trying to solve? Functionally, these will probably do the same thing, but you are now doing an unchecked cast to `TextMessage`. Loggers will typically just call an object's `toString` or print `null`.

Comment: It's checkmarx. The scan is not the actual question, maybe I that was misleading on my post, what I'd like to know is about the casting result. You mentioned I'm now doing an unchecked cast? How do I check it, what do you mean? @ChristopherSchneider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an assumption that you have done unchecked but logically correct cast and toString() method has been overridden in both TextMessage and MapMessage classes, I can say that the cast will not change the result and the overridden toString() method of MapMessage class will be called. Because in case of runtime polymorphism the method is called of the object class.

In case the message is instanceof TextMessage class then the overridden or inherited toString() method of TextMessage class will be called.

Here is a sample program I have done to explain the behavior change in case of runtime polymorphism:

```
class TextMessage {
  String id;
  String message;
  
  TextMessage(String id, String message){
    this.id=id;
    this.message=message;
  }
  
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }
  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TextMessage [id=" + id + ", message=" + message + "]";
  }
}

class MapMessage extends TextMessage{
  String id;
  String message;
  
  MapMessage(String id, String message){
    super(id,message);
    this.id=id;
    this.message=message;
  }
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }
  public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "MapMessage [id=" + id + ", message=" + message + "]";
  }
}

public class MessageTest{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    TextMessage message = new MapMessage("1","Map Message");
    System.out.println("Message1 : " + (TextMessage) message);
    message = new TextMessage("2","Text Message");
    System.out.println("Message2 : " + message);
  }
}
```

The output will be as below:
Message1 : MapMessage [id=1, message=Map Message]
Message2 : TextMessage [id=2, message=Text Message]

Despite casting MapMessage to TextMessage, at runtime MapMessage's overridden toString() method will be called.

I hope it clears your confusion.